# How to Disable Current Date in MaterialDatePicker?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to integrate date selection using MaterialDatePicker. as of now, I can disable past date and future dates by using programmatically. but I am trying to achieve to disable the current date selection along with the future date. please help me. your help will be appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so for your calendarConstraints, you can do

```
calendarConstraints.setEnd(<Replace with today's date>)
```

that should disable the current date and future date

Comment: val calendarConstraints = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
            .setEnd(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)

Comment: I tried this but no luck. can you provide me exact today date format

Comment: btw, the time you use ```Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis``` looks right to me.

It is mostly caused by dateValitorMin, remove that thing and see how it goes. (it might override the setEnd)